# Prove $A \subseteq B \cap C$ if and only if $A \subseteq B$ and $A \subseteq C$

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Prove the following for any sets $A,B$ and $C$.

This is actually two sets that I'm trying the prove. The title character restriction wouldn't allow me to post both at the same time.

a. $A \subseteq B \cap C$ if and only if $A \subseteq B$ and $A \subseteq C$.

Definition 3.1.2 states that we should let A and B be sets. Then $A$ is a subset of $B$, $A \subseteq B$, and the statement $(\forall x)[x \in A \rightarrow \in B ]$ is true.

Proposition 3.1.4 states that $A, B$ and $C$ be sets. If $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq C$, then $A \subseteq C$.

Edit: Proposition 3.1.4 isn't going to work at all.

Definition 3.2.1 states that we have to let A and B be sets.

The intersection of A and B, written as $A \cap B$ is the set $A \cap B$ = $[x: \in A \land x: \in B ]$

The union of A and B, written as $A \cup B$ is the set $A \cup B$ = $[x: \in A \lor x: \in B ]$

Given:
P: $A \subseteq B \cap C$

$A$ is a subset of $B$ intersecting $C$

Q: $A \subseteq B$

A is a subset of B

R: $A \subseteq C$

$A$ is a subset of $C$

We have a bi-conditional statement.

1. If $A \subseteq B \cap C$ then $A \subseteq B$ and $A \subseteq C$
2. If $A \subseteq B$ and $A \subseteq C$ then $A \subseteq B \cap C$.

Edit:

1. If $A \subseteq B \cap C$ then $A \subseteq B$ and $A \subseteq C$

   Using Definition 3.2.1 for $A \subseteq B \cap C$ and Definition 3.1.2 $A \subseteq B$ and $A \subseteq C$, we get

$(\forall x)[x: x \in A \rightarrow x \in B \land x \in A \rightarrow x \in C]$

$(\forall x)[x: x \in A \rightarrow x \in B \land x \in C]$

$(\forall x)[x \in A \rightarrow x \in B]$

$(\forall x) [x \in A \rightarrow x \in C]$

1. For  If $A \subseteq B$ and $A \subseteq C$ then $A \subseteq B \cap C$.

   Using Definition 3.1.2

for $A \subseteq B$ and $A \subseteq C$,

$(\forall x)[(x \in A \rightarrow x \in B)]$

$(\forall x)[(x \in A \rightarrow x \in C)]$

Also, by Definition 3.2.1

$(\forall x)[x : x \in A \rightarrow x \in B \land x \in C]$

$(\forall x)[ x \in A \rightarrow x \in B \land x \in A \rightarrow x \in C]$

---

b. $A \cup B \subseteq C$ if and only if $ A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq C$.

P:$A \cup B \subseteq C$

A unionized B is a subset of C

Q:$ A \subseteq C$

A is a subset of C

R:$B \subseteq C$

B is a subset of C

We have a bi-conditional statement.

1. If $A \cup B \subseteq C$, then $ A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq C$.

Using the union in Definition 3.2.1

$(\forall x)[ x \in A \rightarrow x \in C \rightarrow  \lor x \in B \rightarrow x \in C]$

$(\forall x)[x \in A \lor x \in B \rightarrow x \in C$]

$(\forall x)[x \in A \rightarrow x \in C]$

$(\forall x) [x \in B \rightarrow x \in C]$

1. If $ A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq C$, then $A \cup B \subseteq C$.

Using Definition 3.1.2 for $ A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq C$

$(\forall x)[(x \in A \rightarrow x \in C)]$

$(\forall x)[(x \in B \rightarrow x \in C)]$

Then using Definition 3.2.1\

$(\forall x)[x \in A \lor x \in B \rightarrow x \in C$]

$(\forall x)[ x \in A \rightarrow x \in C \rightarrow  \lor x \in B \rightarrow x \in C]$

Listing what is given to me is very easy. I even identified my P, Q, and R. The statements are in the form of $P \leftrightarrow Q \land R$

Edit: Truth tables won't work.

The problem is how do I go further with this proof?

Maybe after I find out which definition and proposition fits well to this problem, I have to use it to seek what the problem is looking for.

Comment: Hint(huge): $B\cap C\subset B\;,\;C\;$

Comment: Where did that come from? That part was certainly not in my book. Could that be a substitute for A ?

Comment: Well, those are really obvious contentions: the intersection of any number of sets is contained in each and every set taking part in the intersection. It follows directly from the definitions.

Comment: so the B intersecting C is in the subset of B and C?

Comment: Subset of B and also subset of C. Yes, @usu

Comment: ok........I've never seen it like that before.

so since the B intersecting C is in the subset of B and C, 

$(\forall x)[x \in B \cap C \rightarrow \in B \land C ]$

Comment: once again: just think of the definitions. It's trivial.

Comment: DonAntonio is just invoking the definition of intersection. If $x \in B \cap C$, then $x$ must belong to $B$, and, also, to $C$, i.e., the intersection is a subset of each of $B$ and $C$. Now use this argument on each element $x$ of $A$. The case of union is similar: $B, C \subset B \cup C$ by definition of union.

Comment: $A \subseteq B \cap C$ ... $(\forall x)[x \in A \rightarrow \in B \cap C]$

Comment: B and C is in the subset of a B that's unionized with C. 
$(\forall x)[x \in B, \in C \rightarrow \in B \cup C ]$

Comment: I know it is, @ChrisLeary: that's what I wrote twice above.

Comment: $(\forall x)[x \in A \rightarrow \in B \land \in  C]$

Comment: So for b... which is $A \cup B \subseteq C$....

$(\forall x)[x \in C \rightarrow \in A \lor \in  B]$ ???

Comment: @usukidoll - Please, start from *definitions* and work step-by-step. $x \in A \cap B$ iff $x \in A$ and $x \in B$; so, if $x$ belongs to the *intersection* of $A$ **and** $B$, $x$ will belongs to $A$ **and** $x$ will belongs to $B$. If we "split" the original formula, we have that : $ (x \in A \cap B) \rightarrow (x \in A)$ **and** $ (x \in A \cap B) \rightarrow (x \in B)$. But the first is simply : $A \cap B \subseteq A$, while the second is : $A \cap B \subseteq B$.

Comment: @usukidoll - I'm reading the edit version of your question. Regarding *(a)* $A \subseteq B \cap C$ if and only if $A \subseteq B$ and $A \subseteq C$, now "sound good"; you have proved both "directions" of $\rightarrow$, so you have proved the "iff".

Comment: Really? O_O ok ^^ 
Anyway, I'm typing out the second one now...I think I know what to do but the problem is that the letter order is backwords. I'll edit again in a minute to show.

Comment: I've answered with a "polished" version of the first part (*intersection*). About the second part (*union*) I think that you have written the formula in the wrog way : working with $A \cup B \subseteq C$ if and only if $ A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq C$ you should start with : $\forall x( x \in A \lor x \in B \rightarrow x \in C )$ and then you will get : $(x \in A \rightarrow x \in C ) \lor (x \in B \rightarrow x \in C )$, and this is $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq C$.

Comment: Then if I want $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq C$ ... I have to satert with $(x \in A \rightarrow x \in C ) \lor (x \in B \rightarrow x \in C )$ and work my way to $\forall x( x \in A \lor x \in B \rightarrow x \in C )$ with the definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will comment with a line-by-line approach, omitting superfluous comments (please, avoid too many words !) :

This is what we want to prove :

*(a)* $A \subseteq B \cap C$ if and only if $A \subseteq B$ and $A \subseteq C$

> from Definition 3.1.2 --- $A \subseteq B$ is $(\forall x)[x \in A \rightarrow x \in B ]$.
>
> from Definition 3.2.1 --- the intersection of $A$ and $B$, written as $A \cap B$, is the set $A \cap B := \{x: x \in A \land x \in B \}$

We have a bi-conditional statement; so, we need to prove two conditionals :

*(a1)* if $A \subseteq B \cap C$ then $A \subseteq B$ and $A \subseteq C$

*(a2)* if $A \subseteq B$ and $A \subseteq C$ then $A \subseteq B \cap C$.

Demonstration :

***(a1)***

> If $A \subseteq B \cap C$ then $A \subseteq B$ and $A \subseteq C$

Using Definition 3.1.2 we have :

$\forall x ( x \in A \rightarrow x \in B \cap C )$

then, using Definition 3.2.1 and omitting the initial quantifier for brevity :

$( x \in A \rightarrow x \in B \land x \in C )$

$( x \in A \rightarrow x \in B ) \land ( x \in A \rightarrow x \in C )$

that is, using again Definition 3.1.2 :

> $A \subseteq B$ and $A \subseteq C$

***(a2)***

> If $A \subseteq B$ and $A \subseteq C$ then $A \subseteq B \cap C$.

Using the Definition 3.1.2 :

$(\forall x)(x \in A \rightarrow x \in B)$

$(\forall x)(x \in A \rightarrow x \in C)$

Omitting the initial quantifiers we have that :

$(x \in A \rightarrow x \in B) \land (x \in A \rightarrow x \in C)$

$x \in A \rightarrow ( x \in B \land x \in C)$

that is, by Definition 3.2.1 :

$x \in A \rightarrow ( x \in B \cap C)$

and finally, applying again Definition 3.1.2 :

> $A \subseteq B \cap C$.

***Added***

Now for the second part.

*(b)* $A \cup B \subseteq C$ if and only if $ A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq C$.

We have a bi-conditional statement:

***(b1)***

> If $A \cup B \subseteq C$, then $ A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq C$.

$( x \in A \cup B \rightarrow x \in C )$

but $A$ is a subset of $A \cup B$, so that :

$( x \in A \rightarrow x \in A \cup B)$

and, by transitivity of $\rightarrow$ :

> $( x \in A \rightarrow x \in C )$ that is $A \subseteq C$;

the same with : $x \in B$, so that :

> $( x \in B \rightarrow x \in C)$ that is $B \subseteq C$.

***(b2)***

> If $ A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq C$, then $A \cup B \subseteq C$.

$(x \in A \rightarrow x \in C)$

$(x \in B \rightarrow x \in C)$

By definition of *union* :

$(x \in A \cup B \rightarrow (x \in A \lor x \in B) )$

this means that, if $x$ belongs to $A \cup B$, then $x$ belongs to $A$ or $x$ belongs to $B$; but in both cases $x$ belongs to $C$, because $A$ and $B$ are both subsets of $C$, so that :

> $A \cup B \subseteq C$.

Comment: I  have a new problem with the second one. I applied the definitions as usual, and got some strange results in return for

$A \cup B \subseteq C$ if and only if $A \subseteq C$ and $A \subseteq B$

Comment: Thanks. I'm in an Intro to Advanced Mathematics class and I'm a beginner at proofs which is why everything I typed was wordy.

Answer (score 1):

Element chasing, element chasing, element chasing.
You are right in realizing that the truth table will do little for you.
Since sets are uniquely determined by their elements, if you can show that an arbitrary element, say $x$ of one set is also in another you have shown set inclusion in one direction, show it in the other and you have equality.
Since you do not need equality for this you just have to element chase in one direction (but you do still need to prove both directions in the biconditionals you have).
Try translating the set notation into its boolean equivalent, e.g. $x\in A\cup B \iff (x\in A) \lor (x\in B)$.

For a):
$(\implies)$
Let $x\in A$, then by the given condition, $x\in B\cap C$.
How can you show $A\subseteq B$ and $A\subseteq C$ follow from this?

$(\impliedby)$ Suppose $A\subseteq B$ and $A\subseteq C$ and let $x\in A$. What follows from this?

For b):
Let $x\in A\cup B$, can you show then that since $A\cup B\subseteq C$ that every element of $A$ (and $B$) is also in $C$?
The converse?

Comment: For a. 

So for... 
$A \subseteq B \cap C$

Let $x\in A\cup B \iff (x\in A) \lor (x\in B$

sorry... meant to add more

$A \subseteq B$
$x\in A$
$x \in B$


It must come from definition 3.1.2 
$(\forall x)[x \in A \rightarrow \in B ]$
that is for $A \subseteq B$
so for $A \subseteq C$
$(\forall x)[x \in A \rightarrow \in C]$

Comment: @usukidoll I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you are stating.

Comment: $(\forall x)[x \in A \rightarrow \in C ]$
$(\forall x)[x \in B \rightarrow \in C ]$ for the second one.

Comment: I've listed the definitions and propositions for the proof earlier.. I tried to use $(\forall x)[x \in A \rightarrow \in B ]$, but the latex is making everything into one big paragraph.

Comment: $(\forall x)[x\in A\implies x\in B\cap C]$, but $x\in B\cap C$ is equivalent to $(x\in B) \land (x\in C)$

Comment: but for the $A \subseteq B$ since A is in a subset of B....$(\forall x)[x \in A \rightarrow \in B ]$

Comment: same for $A \subseteq C$ ... since A is in the subset of C. ............$(\forall x)[x \in A \rightarrow \in C]$

Comment: @usukidoll - you have a *realtion* between set properties and boolean connectives : *union* ($\cup$) "works with" "or" ($\lor$) and *intersection* ($\cap$) "works with "and" ($\land$). And again : please, at least at the beginning, start with the *definitions* and work step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have some difficulty at imagining those definition. A picture can help you very much.

[image]

Remember also that if

$$•\space A \subset B \implies \forall x\in A , x\in B$$

$$• \space A \subset B\cap C \implies \forall x \in A, x \in B \land x\in C$$

Comment: I'm having a bigger problem with the second part of the question. I have applied the definitions and saw that my C is backwards. I'm supposed to have $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq C$, not $C \subseteq A$ and $C \subseteq B$

Comment: you have to show that $A \subseteq B \cap C$ $\iff$ $A \subseteq B$ and $A \subseteq C$. This means that backwards you have that $A \subseteq B \land A \subseteq C$ with this statement you have to show that $A \subseteq B \cap C$ ;-)

Comment: A is a subset of B intersection C. 
that looks like the first one I did. assuming that's true, I'll have a repeated step.

Comment: No, A subset of B intersection C means that A is a set smaller than the set painted in green in my picture. This means that every elements contained in A is also contained in B and in C, or in symbol A⊆B∩C

Comment: wait which question are we talking about?
I'm talking about
$A \cup B \subseteq C$ if and only if $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq C$

Comment: Ok, but this is not the question of your topic. In this case than you have that every element contained in A is contained in C and every element in B is contained in C, this means that the union of A and B is still contained in C, conversely, if the union of A and B is contained in C means that every element in A is contained in C and every element is contained in B. Draw a picture, everything will be clearer

Comment: I've wrote and I quote, "This is actually two sets that I'm trying the prove. The title character restriction wouldn't allow me to post both at the same time. " 

In a nutshell, I couldn't fit those two statements in the title.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do this: starting at the most complex side we try to transform it into the other side, expanding the definitions, and simplifying.

This results in the following short and straightforward calculation:
\begin{align}
& A \subseteq B \;\land\; A \subseteq C \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\subseteq\;$, twice"} \\
& \langle \forall x : x \in A : x \in B \rangle \;\land\; \langle \forall x : x \in A : x \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: $\;\forall\;$ distributes over $\;\land\;$ -- simplifying, bringing $\;B\;$ and $\;C\;$ closer"} \\
& \langle \forall x : x \in A : x \in B \;\land\; x \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\cap\;$ -- this step is strongly suggested by our goal"} \\
& \langle \forall x : x \in A : x \in B \cap C \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\subseteq\;$"} \\
& A \subseteq B \cap C \\
\end{align}
which proves the first statement (from the title).

Similarly, for the second statement
\begin{align}
& A \subseteq C \;\land\; A \subseteq C \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\subseteq\;$, twice"} \\
& \langle \forall x : x \in A : x \in C \rangle \;\land\; \langle \forall x : x \in B : x \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: merge the ranges of two quantifications"} \\
& \langle \forall x : x \in A \;\lor\; x \in B : x \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\cup\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x : x \in A \cup B : x \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\subseteq\;$"} \\
& A \cup B \subseteq C \\
\end{align}
which completes the proof.